# How to remove/disable transition in durandal

Tags: durandal

I search how to deactivate the transition on compose data-bind, 
because it not beautiful and little bug with my content html on chrome.
Because i have a scroll horizontal print on end on my transition and disaspear after move my mouse.
The content is in iFrame.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable transitions for compose by removing the "transition" option from the binding declaration.

Instead of:

```
<div data-bind="router: { cacheViews: false, transition: 'entrance' }"></div>
```

use:

```
<div data-bind="router: { cacheViews: false }"></div>
```

This example is for Durandal 2.0, although earlier versions work the same way.

There's more info in the docs [here](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition/) in the "Additional Settings" section.

(The transition framework is pluggable, so you can also write your own, using the default "entrance" transition as an example.)

Answer (score 4):

Also need to remove the second parameter in setRoot call:

```
// Was
app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');

// Done
app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell');
```